# If else loop in python doesn't function properly

Tags: python, if-statement, error-handling, logic, runtime-error

so i'm writing a program that's supposed to take 2 inputs of data as int's for a user's debt. the variables are debt1 and debt2. it's supposed to add these two values together and then depending on the user's input, it's supposed to give out a specific response using the "if/else" loop i've created. the problem is that the program only prints out the response from the first "if" statement no matter what the input is, it always prints out "your debt is dangerously high". how do i correct this?

** Here is my code **

```
Name = input("Please enter your name: ")

debt1 = int(input("Please enter your first debt amount: "))
debt2 = int(input("Please enter your second debt amount: "))

totalDebt = debt1+debt2
print("Your total debt is ", totalDebt)

if (totalDebt > 900,000):
    print("Your debt is dangerously high ", Name)

elif((totalDebt >= 450,000 and totalDebt < 900,000)):
    print("We can help you reduce your debt.")

else:
    print("Congratulations, you know how to manage debt.")
```

Comment: `900,000` is not a valid number

Comment: In python 3, you can use `_`  in place of `,` for numbers with lots of zeros. `900_000` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use commas in numbers:

```
if totalDebt > 900000:
    print("Your debt is dangerously high ", Name)
elif (totalDebt >= 450000 and totalDebt < 900000):
    print("We can help you reduce your debt.")
else:
    print("Congratulations, you know how to manage debt.")
```

As @rdas said, you can use `_` for long numbers, in place of `,`

Comment: yeah the comma was the main issue, thanks. when i get rid of the commas and just leave zeros, the program still makes no sense for the elif and the else statement. for example,  when the total debt is less than 450,000; it prints out "congratulations, you know how to manage debt", but it also prints out the result from the second statement which is "we can help you reduce your debt" when it's not supposed to when value is less than 450,000

Comment: @Madridista94 what input are you using? And are you executing this right inside a shell like Terminal?